# SQL string literal hexadecimal key to binary and back

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, hex, checksum

after extensive search I am resorting to stack-overflows wisdom to help me.
Problem:
I have a database table that should effectively store values of the format `(UserKey, data0, data1, ..)` where the `UserKey` is to be handled as primary key but at least as an index. The UserKey itself (externally defined) is a string of 32 characters representing a checksum, which happens to be (a very big) hexadecimal number, i.e. it looks like this `UserKey = "000000003abc4f6e000000003abc4f6e"`.

Now I can certainly store this UserKey in a char(32)-field, but I feel this being mighty inefficient, as I store a series of in principle arbitrary characters, i.e. reserving space for for more information per character than the 4 bits i need to store the hexadecimal characters (0..9,A-F).

So my thought was to convert this string literal into the hex-number it really represents, and store that. But this number (32*4 bits = 16Bytes) is much too big to store/handle as SQL only handles BIGINTS of 8Bytes.

My second thought was to convert this into a BINARY(16) representation, which should be compact and efficient concerning memory. However, I do not know how to efficiently convert between these two formats, as SQL also internally only handles numbers up to the maximum of 8 Bytes.

Maybe there is a way to convert this string to binary block by block and stitch the binary together somehow, in the way of:

```
 UserKey == concat( stringblock1, stringblock2, ..)
 UserKey_binary = concat( toBinary( stringblock1 ), toBinary( stringblock2 ), ..)
```

So my question is: is there any such mechanism foreseen in SQL that would solve this for me? How would a custom solution look like? (I find it hard to believe that I should be the first to encounter such a problem, as it has become quite modern to use ridiculously long hashkeys in many applications)

Also, the `Userkey_binary` should than act as relational key for the table, so I hope for a bit of speed by this more compact representation, as it needs to determine the difference on a minimal number of bits. Additionally, I want to mention that I would like to do any conversion if possible on the Server-side, so that user-scripts have not to be altered (the user-side should, if possible, still transmit a string literal not [partially] converted values in the insert statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Contradiction to my previous statement, it seems that MySQL's `UNHEX()` function does a conversion from a string block by block and then concat much like I stated above, so the method works also for HEX literal values which are bigger than the BIGINT's 8 byte limitation. Here an example table that illustrates this:

```
CREATE TABLE `testdb`.`tab` (
`hexcol_binary` BINARY(16) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UNHEX(charcol)) STORED,
`charcol` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`hexcol_binary`));
```

The primary key is a generated column, so that that updates to charcol are the designated way of interacting with the table with string literals from the outside:

```
REPLACE into tab (charcol) VALUES ('1010202030304040A0A0B0B0C0C0D0D0');
SELECT HEX(hexcol_binary) as HEXstring, tab.* FROM tab;
```

as seen building keys and indexes on the hexcol_binary works as intended.

To verify the speedup, take

```
ALTER TABLE `testdb`.`tab` 
ADD INDEX `charkey` (`charcol` ASC);
EXPLAIN SELECT * from tab where  hexcol_binary = UNHEX('1010202030304040A0A0B0B0C0C0D0D0') #keylength 16
EXPLAIN SELECT * from tab where charcol = '1010202030304040A0A0B0B0C0C0D0D0' #keylength 97
```

the lookup on the hexcol_binary column is much better performing, especially if its additonally made unique.

Note: the hex conversion does not care if the hex-characters A through F are capitalized or not for the conversion process, however the charcol will be very sensitive to this.